# Unmarshalling XML into Java object JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am having a XML document as follows,

```
<Configuration>
<Shop>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Block>
        <Items>
            <Item>Basic</Item>
        </Items>
    </Block>
</Shop>
<Shop>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Block>
        <Items>
            <Item>Basic</Item>
            <Item>Pin</Item>
        </Items>
    </Block>
</Shop></Configuration>
```

And have classes as follows,

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
class ShopConfig {
private List<Shop> shops;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Configuration", nillable = false)
@XmlElement(name = "Shop", nillable = false)
public List<Shop> getShops() {
    return shops;
}
public void setShops(List<Shop> shops) {
    this.shops = shops;
}
public void print(){
    for(Shop shop: shops){
        List<String> l = shop.getItemNames();
        for(String s : l){
            System.out.println(s);

        }
    }
}
}

public class Shop {
private String level;
private List<String> itemNames;
public String getLevel() {
    return level;
}
@XmlElement(name = "Level")
public void setLevel(String level) {
    this.level = level;
}
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Items", nillable = false)
@XmlElement(name = "Item", nillable = false)
public List<String> getItemNames() {
    return itemNames;
}
public void setItemNames(List<String> itemNames) {
    this.itemNames = itemNames;
}
}
```

I unmarshall the xml as follows,

```
private static ShopConfig initShopConfig() throws JAXBException {
    String configPath = "Config.xml";
    File file = new File(configPath);
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ShopConfig.class);
    Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
    return  (ShopConfig) um.unmarshal(file);
}
```

But when I am trying to print it gives NPE when I try to call print method saying shops variable is null. It means it didn't unmarshall properly. What wrong am I doing here?

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    ShopConfig l = (ShopConfig)ConfigLoader.getInstance().getConfig();
    l.print();
}
```

The exception is not informative,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at config.ShopConfig.print(ShopConfig.java:42)
at config.Test.main(Test.java:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Always share the exception trace when you are posting a question related to getting an exception.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the exception, I have appended it. But it doesn't give much information.

Comment: what is line#42. My guess is; shops list is null.

Comment: Line 42 is,   for(Shop shop: shops){. Yes shops is null. I debugged and checked, the unmarshal method returns null. I think  there is something wrong in my annotation for JAXB, may be that is why it couldn't unmarshal. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Give a try after removing `@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Configuration", nillable = false)`. Seems XML and Java Class mapping has some issue.

Comment: @Abimaran That improves. Once I removed that annotation shops are getting initialized but not the items. Now a NPE is thrown in for(String s : l){.

Comment: @Ragavan, You have missed `Block` element in your JAVA mapping.

Comment: @Abimaran How the annotation for the Block element should be done in this case?

Comment: Block should be mapped to a separate Java class, which will have list of Items. Shop will have Block, and Block will have list of Items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55809/discussion-between-ragavan-thiru-and-abimaran-kugathasan).